# Office.JS Word API - Can't update property fields from ExecuteFunction in manifest

Tags: ms-word, office-js, office-addins, word-addins, word-web-addins

I have an Office web add-in for Word that needs to fetch custom properties from an API and store them under `document.properties.customProperties` the user will then be able to insert them into their document as a DocProperty field. This is done using the following code snippet:

```
await Word.run(async (context) => {
    var range = context.document.getSelection().getRange();

    range.insertField(Word.InsertLocation.after, Word.FieldType.docProperty, '"' + req.property + '"', false);
    await context.sync();

    dialog.close();
});
```

This all works fine and I can see that the custom properties are being set correctly. My problem occurs when trying to update the fields. Simply using "Select All + F9" won't work in my case since I first need to fetch the custom properties from an API to make sure they are up-to-date so my only option is using a custom Ribbon button.

The updating of the fields is done using the following snippet:

```
async function updateAllFields(event) {

    await Word.run(async (context) => {
        // fetch properties from API
        await getFileProperties()

        context.document.body.fields.load();
        await context.sync()

        var field = context.document.body.fields.getFirstOrNullObject();

        await updateField(context, field)
    });

    event.completed();
}

async function updateField(context, field) {
    await field.load();
    await context.sync();

    if (field.isNull) {
        return;
    }

    await field.updateResult();
    await context.sync();

    const nextField = field.getNextOrNullObject();
    if (nextField) {
        await updateField(context, nextField);
    }
}
```

When I execute the updateAllFields function through the console it works exactly as expected, but when I try to run it through a Ribbon button it simply fails without errors.

Some information that might be relevant

- The requested permissions are `ReadWriteDocument`
- The action is defined as follows

  ```
    <Action xsi:type="ExecuteFunction">
         <FunctionName>updateAllFields</FunctionName>
    </Action>
  ```
- The add-in uses the `SharedRuntime` option.

Comment: Try to post this as an issue to https://github.com/OfficeDev/office-js/issues .

Answer (score 0):

I see a couple problems with your code. First the line `if (nextField)` should be `if (!(nextField.isNull))`. The way you have written it, it is always going to be true because you are testing for the existence of the **proxy** object and since you just created it in the preceding line, it always exists. What you want to test is whether the corresponding object **in the Word doc** exists.

Second, your code is kind of hard to read because you've got the test for `field.isNull` inside a subfunction. The best practice when an object might be null is to test for nullity before you do **anything** with the object, including passing it to a subfunction.